# Why are some items not translated in Odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo

I have a problem with translations in **Project** module. Some menu items are not translated. What could be the problem?

[image]

Here **project_view.xml**

```xml
<!-- Top menu item -->
<menuitem name="Project"
    id="base.menu_main_pm"
    groups="group_project_manager,group_project_user"
    icon="fa-calendar"
    web_icon="project,static/description/icon.png"
    sequence="50"/>
```

Here **ru.po**

```
#. module: project
#: model:ir.model,name:project.model_project_project
#: model:ir.model.fields,field_description:project.field_project_task_history_cumulative_project_id
#: model:ir.model.fields,field_description:project.field_project_task_project_id
#: model:ir.model.fields,field_description:project.field_report_project_task_user_project_id
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:project.edit_project
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:project.view_task_form2
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:project.view_task_history_search
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:project.view_task_project_user_search
#: model:ir.ui.view,arch_db:project.view_task_search_form
#: model:res.request.link,name:project.req_link_project
msgid "Project"
msgstr "Проект"
```

Comment: Sometimes translations don't work very well. Try pressing the "Update" button in the "Base" module

Comment: @ChesuCR thank you very much. This solved the problem on version 8. Tomorrow I will try this solution on version 9.

Comment: You are welcome :) I wrote the comment as an answer, please check it as a correct answer!! Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've also had this problem with translations. I had updated module `base` a lot of times too and it worked, but sometimes it wasn't necessary. What I did is the next process:

- Go to *Settings > Translations > Load a Translation*, select your
  language and check the box *Overwrite Existing Terms*, then click on
  *Load* button.
- After that, press F5 to refresh the browser, then go to *Settings >
  Translations > Application Terms > Synchronize Terms*, select your
  language and click on *Update*. Then press again F5 to see if your
  terms have been updated.

Regards.

Comment: It is weird... Items on left menu was translated. But item on **top menu** was not changed. [Here screen](http://prntscr.com/90qlpe). Do you have any idea? I dance with drum a lot of time :(((

Comment: As I understood, translation for top item **Project** store in `/odoo/openerp/addons/base/i18n/ru.po`. Here source from file `#. module: base
#: model:ir.module.category,name:base.module_category_project_management
#: model:ir.ui.menu,name:base.menu_main_pm
msgid "Project"
msgstr "Проект"`

Comment: Yes, that's weird. Every term should have been translated. But now you were able to translate terms on left side doing synchronization, try to update your module, and press F5, and repeat the process above. If you can't see your translation in the top menu, then try to update `base`, just in case (may be after the synchronization it works).

Comment: It is so strange... Now I tried this solution after reinstallation odoo 9. Even left menu items have not translated. I don't know why. I installed only module `project` and nothing else.

Comment: Yes, it drives us crazy. In version 8, this always happened to me with the module `purchase`. The module was translated to my language during the installation, except for some terms (the top menu option was one of these). So I always refreshed the browser, did the process what I told you in my answer, and, if nothing happened, updated `base`, repeated the process of the answer again, and if same problem, then I updated my own module and repeated the process again. After those attempts, I managed that the translation was updated as I needed. Sometimes actually kind of fluke...

Comment: I have just come up with another idea. **Try to remove the browser cache** before and after doing the processes I told you. It worked for me sometimes when I had to face off this kind of problem. Good luck ;)

Comment: I removed cache before. I think issue not in cache. I'll try the solution again with clear odoo.

Comment: It is works! Thank you so much! Good luck in development ;)))

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes translations don't work very well. Try pressing the "Update" button in the "Base" module. This should solve the problem.

### Update: 21 nov 2019

I do not know in older versions, but now there are more options in command line to update, import and export translations. The argument `--i18n-overwrite` might be useful in your case:

```
Use these options to translate Odoo to another language. See i18n
section of the user manual. Option '-d' is mandatory. Option '-l' is
mandatory in case of importation

--load-language=LOAD_LANGUAGE
                    specifies the languages for the translations you want
                    to be loaded
-l LANGUAGE, --language=LANGUAGE
                    specify the language of the translation file. Use it
                    with --i18n-export or --i18n-import
--i18n-export=TRANSLATE_OUT
                    export all sentences to be translated to a CSV file, a
                    PO file or a TGZ archive and exit
--i18n-import=TRANSLATE_IN
                    import a CSV or a PO file with translations and exit.
                    The '-l' option is required.
--i18n-overwrite    overwrites existing translation terms on updating a
                    module or importing a CSV or a PO file.
--modules=TRANSLATE_MODULES
                    specify modules to export. Use in combination with
                    --i18n-export
```

Comment: This solution works on version 8. But in version 9 problem still exist (((. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: mm that's too bad :/ I didn't work with the version 9 yet. I don't know if the languages are translated in the same way. After updating the base module try to update your custom module as well.

Comment: Your solution decides my problem. I could not understand why this way working on 'clear' odoo, but not working on my project. So, I check subversions and found that they are different. After update project to last subversion your solution working is good. Thank you so much!

Comment: I discovered it just now

Comment: AAh! It's a pity that you gave the reputation points to @forvas instead of me xD

Comment: Year ((( But it's' too late ((

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, is not enough to update the base module. I implemented a solution based on a post. What I do is clear the whole language using a query, and then reload the language again using. "Load a Translation" from config menu.

The query that made it possible, is the following, for example for es_CL:

DELETE FROM ir_translation WHERE lang = 'es_CL';

I've put this in a module, which you can use to adapt it to your needs:

https://github.com/odoo-chile/l10n_cl_clear_translation

When this module is instaled it runs the query. Then you can reload your language using the menu.

Comment: Thanks. I forget about `ir_translation`. I found it but later... Anyway this is useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sometimes the localization doesn't work perfectly. Here's another strategy from v8, which may still help you in v9.

- First, update your module like described
- Then, remove all translated strings for your module from the database. This is safe, because you have them in your ru.po file.

  - Go to Settings > Translations > Application Terms > Translated Terms
  - Do an "Advanced Search" with 'Module' 'contains'  to find all your terms
  - select them all (possibly set the pager to 'unlimited')
  - Select 'More' > 'Delete'
  - Confirm
- Update your module again.
- Export the ru.po file again; it should now contain all missing terms.

The issue seems to be that the module sometimes takes some values from the default (en) language into the target language, which then prohibits the term to be listed as 'to be translated'.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this solution on version 9. I'll let you know.

Comment: Nothing changed (((. After update **base** module I see new _Translated Terms_, but menu item still without translation.